# Excel to ppt with pictures in the cells

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am creating a presentation from an excel document that will repeat the same data on every slide. When the excel is updated, I would like to be able to refresh the ppt. by running the macro. The text is copying over and displaying correctly on the slides, but I am having trouble with the pictures located in the cells on the excel sheet. Is there a way to have the pictures in the cell copy and paste into each slide as they are created and if not, what is the best approach to achieve this?

```
Sub Create_Deck()
'create slide for each name in list
'fill two text boxes
Dim myPT As Presentation
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim wbA As Object
Dim wsA As Object
Dim myList As Object
Dim myRng As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim col01 As Long
Dim col02 As Long
Dim col03 As Long
Dim col04 As Long
Dim col05 As Long
Dim col06 As Long
Dim col07 As Long
Dim col08 As Long
Dim col09 As Long
Dim col10 As Long
Dim col11 As Long
Dim col12 As Long


'columns with text for slides
col01 = 2
col02 = 3
col03 = 4
col04 = 5
col05 = 6
col06 = 7
col07 = 8
col08 = 9
col09 = 11
col10 = 15
col11 = 14
col12 = 1

On Error Resume Next
 Set myPT = ActivePresentation
 Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
 Set wbA = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
 Set wsA = wbA.ActiveSheet
Set myList = wsA.ListObjects(1)
On Error GoTo errHandler

If Not myList Is Nothing Then

  Set myRng = myList.DataBodyRange

  For i = 1 To myRng.Rows.Count
      With myPT
        'Copy first slide, paste after last slide
         .Slides(1).Copy
         .Slides.Paste (myPT.Slides.Count + 1)
  
         'change text in 1st textbox
         .Slides(.Slides.Count) _
           .Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
             = myRng.Cells(i, col01).Value
     
         'change text in 2nd textbox
         .Slides(.Slides.Count) _
           .Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
             = myRng.Cells(i, col02).Value
         
         'change text in 3rd textbox
        .Slides(.Slides.Count) _
           .Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
             = myRng.Cells(i, col03).Value
         
        'change text in 4th textbox
         .Slides(.Slides.Count) _
           .Shapes(4).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
             = myRng.Cells(i, col04).Value
         
        'change text in 5th textbox
         .Slides(.Slides.Count) _
           .Shapes(5).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
             = myRng.Cells(i, col05).Value
         
        'change text in 6th textbox
         .Slides(.Slides.Count) _
           .Shapes(6).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
             = myRng.Cells(i, col06).Value
         
             'change text in 7th textbox
         .Slides(.Slides.Count) _
           .Shapes(7).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
             = myRng.Cells(i, col07).Value
         
         'change text in 8th textbox
         .Slides(.Slides.Count) _
            .Shapes(8).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
             = myRng.Cells(i, col08).Value
         
             'change text in 9th textbox
         .Slides(.Slides.Count) _
           .Shapes(9).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
             = myRng.Cells(i, col09).Value
         
            'change text in 10th textbox
         .Slides(.Slides.Count) _
           .Shapes(10).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
             = myRng.Cells(i, col10).Value
         
          'change text in 11th textbox
         .Slides(.Slides.Count) _
           .Shapes(11).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
             = myRng.Cells(i, col11).Value
          
        Adds Picture
          .Slides(.Slides.Count) _
           .Shapes(12).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
             = myRng.Cells(i, col12).Value
  
      End With
  Next
Else
  MsgBox "No Excel table found on active sheet"
  GoTo exitHandler
End If

exitHandler:
  Exit Sub
errHandler:
  MsgBox "Could not complete slides"
  Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: In Excel a picture is not "in" a cell, only positioned *over* it - you cannot access the picture by reading the cell's value - you'd need to loop over all the Shapes on the sheet and find the one whose `TopLeftCell` property matches the cell of interest, and then copy/paste that over to PPT.  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526293/selecting-all-the-shapes-in-a-cell for how to check whether a shape is over a specific cell.

Comment: You might want to look here:  it's someone asking the same question, with an actual working example of the solution!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595659/copying-picture-from-excel-to-powerpoint

Comment: Ah, I see that since I found this question yesterday, @TimWilliams has posted a reply, with a different link!  That's cool!

Answer (score 0):

Lightly tested:

```vb
Sub Create_Deck()

    Dim myPT As Presentation, myList As Object
    Dim myRng As Object, i As Long
    Dim cols, col, sld As Slide, shpNum As Long, pic As Object
    
    'use an array to store the listobject columns we want to extract from
    cols = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 15, 14, 1) 

    Set myPT = ActivePresentation
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set myList = GetObject(, "Excel.Application").ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    On Error GoTo 0        'stop ignoring errors
    
    If myList Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Excel not open, or no table found on active sheet", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set myRng = myList.DataBodyRange
    
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    For i = 1 To myRng.Rows.Count
        'Copy first slide, paste after last slide
        With myPT
            .Slides(1).Copy
            .Slides.Paste .Slides.Count + 1
            Set sld = .Slides(.Slides.Count)
        End With
        
        shpNum = 0
        For col = 0 To UBound(cols)
            shpNum = shpNum + 1
            Select Case True
                Case cols(col) <> 14
                    sld.Shapes(shpNum).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
                                   myRng.Cells(i, cols(col)).Value
                Case Else
                    Set pic = GetCellShape(myRng.Cells(i, cols(col)))
                    If Not pic Is Nothing Then
                        pic.Copy
                        ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide sld.SlideIndex
                        DoEvents
                        sld.Shapes(shpNum).Select
                        Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Paste"
                        DoEvents
                    End If
            End Select
        Next col
    Next i

    Exit Sub
    
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not complete slides - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
End Sub

'Return the first shape on the same sheet as cell `c`
'  or Nothing if no shape was found over that cell
Function GetCellShape(c As Object) As Object
    Dim ws As Object, shp As Object
    Set ws = c.worksheet
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        If shp.topleftcell.Address = c.Address Then
            Set GetCellShape = shp
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next shp
End Function
```